# Firefox not rendering list item as a link

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've never come across this problem before and its quite annoying me. I have a list which when hovered over, a box appears around it. 
I have a list set out like the following

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Our Services</h2>

    <ul>
        <a href="furniture.php"><li>Furniture</li></a>
        <a href="kitchens.php"><li>Kitchens</li></a>
        <a href="bedrooms.php"><li>Bedrooms</li></a>
        <a href="flooring.php"><li>Flooring</li></a>
        <a href="externaljoinery.php"><li>External Joinery</li></a>
        <a href="commercialwork.php"><li>Commercial Work</li></a>
        <a href="staircases.php"><li>Staircases</li></a>
        <a href="tiling.php"><li>Tiling</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But for some reason firefox doesnt render the whole list item as a link, only the text.
It works across other browsers (even IE) but not firefox.

Comment: You might want to look into using Total Validator (http://totalvalidator.com/tool/index.html). It's a great tool for checking if a page has correct HTML syntax (it also checks for additional things, such as accessibility and broken links).

Answer (score 12):

Change

```
<a href="furniture.php"><li>Furniture</li></a>
```

To

```
<li><a href="furniture.php">Furniture</a></li>
```

Inside a `UL` you are supposed to have `LI` elements, not anything else. However, inside the `LI` you can have other tags such as `A`

**Update**

You can set the style of `A` to `display:block` as `mwgriffith` suggested on comments.

or to make the whole line a link you can also assign a click event on the `LI`, [here is an example using jQuery](http://jsbin.com/ekuda3/3/edit)

Comment: Is `<ul><a href="furniture.php"><li>Furniture</li></a></ul>` valid HTML anyway?

Comment: No, you can't have any tags but `LI` directly under `UL`

Comment: That is unfortunatly not doing what I want, if I put the <a> inside the <li> then only the text is a link, instead of the whole list which all browsers except firefox is doing.

For example, I have the list item as 50px wide and 30px high, and all browsers are rendering the list item as a link like I want, except firefox which renders only the text as a link.

Comment: You might be able to use display:block; on the either the li or a href tags and it might work the way you want it too.

Comment: A tip: validate. http://validator.w3.org/ tells you exactly what the problems are.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of having the `<li>` display the background I used `display:block` on the `<a>` tags and uses the `a:hover` to create the background.